# How to override controllers in Pimcore plugins

Tags: zend-framework, pimcore, zend-framework-modules

In one of my projects, i have a third party plugin installed. Plugins are, from my understanding, a regular module in the Zend Framework sense (framework version 1.12 in this case).

Is there a way override the controllers shipped with the plugin with my own implementation without changing the module itself? I was think of something like "Check for a controller from a certain namespace first; if it doesn't exist, fall back to the one from the module".

What i am ultimately trying to achieve is to extend the module in a "hidden" or transparent way, so that i do not have to change the default routing, and the application will still look and work the same from a users perspective.

If thats not possible, what is best practice to extend a Pimcore plugin or a Zend Module in general?

Answer (score -2):

When overriding functions of an Plugin you should create your own Class and Extend the Plugin ones: https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Parent_Class_for_Objects.html

If needed you may then use DI https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Dependency_Injection.html to always instantiate your Overriding Class which could / should extend or use then back the origin class.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have updated my answer accordingly.